# Passing value from hidden field to controller MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I basically have a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped" id="tabelaIzostanci">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Ime i prezime</b></td>
      <td><b>Predmet</b></td>
      <td><b>Profesor</b></td>
      <td><b>Razlog</b></td>
      <td><b>Opravdano</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@item.Ucenik.Ime @item.Ucenik.Prezime</td>
        <td>@item.Cas.Predmet.Naziv</td>
        <td>@item.Cas.Nastavnik.Ime @item.Cas.Nastavnik.Prezime</td>
        @if (item.Napomena == "")
        {
          <td>Napomena nije unesena.</td>
        }
        else
        {
          <td>@item.Napomena</td>
        }
        @if (item.Opravdano == false)
        {
          <td>Ne</td>
        }
        else
        {
          <td>Da</td>
        }
        <td>
          <form>
            <button type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility('toggle');" class="btn btn-primary">Opravdaj</button>
            <input  type="hidden" id="txtID" name="test" value="@item.OdsutnostID"/>
          </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The button that I have is outside of table and looks like this:

```
<button style="float:right; width:100px;" type="button" onclick="CallMe()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

The Javascript function that I'm using is:

```
 function CallMe() {
       if ($('#txtID').val() !== '') {
           $.ajax({
               url: '/Controller/Action',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { txtID: $('#txtID').val(),
               success: function (data) {
                  Alert('Success');
               },
               error: function (error) {
                   alert('Error: ' + error);

               }
           });
       }
```

And my Action looks like this:

```
Public ActionResult Action(string txtID)
{
// checking whether the ID is there
}
```

The function is called, but the passed ID from View to Controller is always static, and somehow is always marked as "1". If I click on the 2nd record in table which has the ID = 2, the passed ID is still =1;

I can't use the model because its being used for something else.. So my question is, is there any way I can pass the ID dynamically from View to Controller without having to use the model??

Or could someone help me out why is the ID always = 1?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the button for showing and hiding the form:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if (e.style.display == 'block') 
           e.style.display = 'none';
       else 
           e.style.display = 'block';
   }
```

Comment: Because you have invalid html (duplicate `id` atributes) and `$('#txtID').val()` will only ever return the value of the first element with `id="txtID"`.

Comment: So how can I do this so that the value is passed dynamically and correctly??

Comment: You have said the button is _outside the table_ which makes no sense - how are you determining which 'row' value you want to post?

Comment: Well I do have two buttons... One button is in the table, and basically what it does, once its pressed, it shows the form below the table to fill the textarea, and once the button below the textarea is pressed, the contents of the table should be updated...

Comment: You will need to show the code including the any script associated with the buttons in the table

Comment: I updated my question with the button included within the table. So basically what first button does is shows the textarea below the table, and once the textarea is filled out with data, 2nd button should be  pressed and update that exact row which was selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103654/discussion-between-perkes456-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments your wanting to display a textarea when you click a button in a row, and then post the value of the text area and the `OdsutnostID` value of the item in the row to a controller method.

Firstly, stop polluting your html with behavior and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). While you can add a hidden input for `OdsutnostID` and use relative selectors to extract the value, its easier to just delete this and add the value as a `data-` attribute. The html for the last `<td>` element should be

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="edit btn btn-primary" data-id="@item.OdsutnostID">Opravdaj</button>
</td>
```

You have not shown the html for the `textarea` to edit the value of property `Napomena` but it should be something like

```
<div id="form" style="display:none">
    <textarea id="napomena"><textarea>
    <button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Then the scripts will be

```
var id = null;
var row = null;
var form = $('#form');
var textarea = $('#napomena');
var url = '@Url.Action("Action")';

$('.edit').click(function() {
  id = $(this).data('id'); // save the row id in global variable
  row = $(this).closest('tr'); // save current row in global variable
  textarea.val(row.children('td').eq(3).text()); // update the textarea with the current value
  form.show(); // display the 'form'
});

$('#save').click(function() {
    $.post(url, { id: id, text: textarea.val() }, function(data) {
        if(data) {
            row.children('td').eq(3).text(textarea.val()); // update the value in the row
            form.hide(); // hide the form
        }
    });
});
```

which will post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string id, string text)
{
   // save the data
   return Json(true);
}
```

Side note: A few improvements you can make to the view

1. For the table header, use `<th>Predmet</th>`, not
   `<td><b>Predmet</b></td>` (the default style of `th` is bold, but it
   also means that its easier to style your header elements.
2. Add a `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Napomena nije unesena")]`
   attribute to property `Napomena` and then in the view its just
   `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Napomena)</td>` (your `if` block is
   not necessary).
3. Create a `DisplayTemplate` for `bool` which generates `"Ne"` or
   `"Da"` based on the value so that you can use just
   `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Opravdano,
   "nameOfYourTemplate")</td>` rather than an `if` block.

Comment: I've tried the code u pasted entirely, it doesn't shows nor hides the textarea, and when I try to do the postback it doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Then I'm guessing you didn't do it correctly :). Start debugging the scripts to ensure they are being hit and check there are no error messages in the console.

Comment: Have created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jv8fubh8/)** for you to show how it works :)

Comment: Hey, I've copied ur code from fiddle into my cshtml page, exactly as you shown it on fiddle! But it doesn't do anything ?? :(

Comment: What error messages are you getting in the browser console? Have you included jquery?

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
var form = $('#form');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103715/discussion-between-perkes456-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Hey, is there any way that I can put in a validation for the textarea now in that function? Like if the textarea is empty, i'd just do alert('Gotta enter something')? :)

Comment: Yes. But I need some sleep - I'll update the answer tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a class instead and have a button near the class to trigger what you want to do

`<input type="hidden" class="txtIds" value="@item.ID" />`

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary triggerClosestId">trigger Id</button>`

assuming you have jQuery you can do this

```
$('body').on('click', '.triggerClosestId' function () {
    var closestTxtId = $(this).closest('txtIds');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { txtID: closestTxtId .val(),
        success: function (data) {
           alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```